# EOFException in Spring REST

Tags: java, spring

So I have DataStructure that I want to persist in my Spring REST application.
This is how I'm initializing the `@bean`

```
@Configuration
public class MessageBrokerInitializer {

    @Bean
    public MessageBroker getMessageBroker(){

        FileInputStream fileInputStream;
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream;
        MessageBroker broker = null;
        try {
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("./data/store.ser");
            objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
            broker = (MessageBroker) objectInputStream.readObject();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return (broker == null) ? new MessageBroker(): broker;
    }



}
```

Basically I'm trying to read a file initialize my object or if the file is empty I want to new up the data structure. I keep getting,

`java.io.EOFException`

How can I get this working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid `EOFException` by checking `objectInputStream.available()` for the number of bytes that can be read as shown below:

```
@Configuration
public class MessageBrokerInitializer {

    @Bean
    public MessageBroker getMessageBroker(){

        FileInputStream fileInputStream;
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream;
        MessageBroker broker = null;
        try {
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("./data/store.ser");

            if(fileInputStream.available() != 0) {
              objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
              broker = (MessageBroker) objectInputStream.readObject();
            } else {
              broker = new MessageBroker()
           }               
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return broker;
    }
}
```

You can look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html)

Comment: Well even this throws EOF. How do I read a file with no content.

Comment: what it comes when you try to debug the value for objectInputStream.available() ? is it 0 ?

Comment: I fixed it by moving the `available()` one level up, as in checking `fileInputStream.available()`